# integrating a function with absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

i don't know precisely how to deal with it, i just thought i could use the signum function but it's my first time dealing with it so i don't know if it is fine and especcially how to proceed further, anyway this is what i tried:
$$ \int_{-2}^{1} ||x+1|-1| \,dx =   \int_{-2}^{1} |(x+1)sgn(x+1)-1| $$    $$=\int_{-2}^{1}   [(x+1)sgn(x+1)-1) sgn[(  (x+1)sgn(x+1)-1]$$       $$=\int_{-2}^{1}   [(x+1)sgn(x+1) ]sgn[(  (x+1)sgn(x+1)-1] -\int_{-2}^{1}   sgn[  (x+1)sgn(x+1)-1]$$$$= \int_{-2}^{1}   [(x+1)sgn(x+1) ]sgn[(  (x+1)sgn(x+1)-1] -[xsgn[  (x+1)sgn(x+1)-1]^1_{-2} ] $$

i don't know how to proceed, do i need for example to substitute something for then integrating by parts?  Anyway thanks for the responses and sorry for the bad English and the bad brackets

Comment: Split the integal into two parts: One from $-2$ to $-1$ and the other  from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Throughout all of calculus, the only real way to deal with absolute value is to split your expression into the pieces where the argument was positive and where the argument was negative.  After you get to the end, you can often combine the pieces (often using signum), but trying to get through an absolute value problem without splitting the expression is just asking for headaches.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use the sign function, you just have to reason about the sign of the integrand. First of all, split the integral:
$$ \int_{-2}^1 ||x+1|-1| dx=\int_{-2}^{-1} ||x+1|-1| dx+\int_{-1}^1 ||x+1|-1| dx$$
Consider the second integral and note that if $x\in [-1,1]$, then $|x+1|=x+1$. So you have:
$$\int_{-1}^1 ||x+1|-1| dx=\int_{-1}^1 |x| dx=-\int_{-1}^0xdx+\int_0^1xdx=1 $$
Now, as we've done before, note that if $x\in[-2,-1]$, you have $|x+1|=-x-1$:
$$\int_{-2}^{-1} ||x+1|-1| dx=\int_{-2}^{-1} |-x-2| dx=\int_{-2}^{-1} (x+2) dx=\frac{1}{2} $$
Finally you have:
$$ \int_{-2}^1 ||x+1|-1| dx=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just graph the function, the integral is $3$ times the area of triangle $ABC$, by using the fact that an integral represents the algebraic area between x-axis and the function's curve.

Also using the fact that absolute value of linear functions is piecewise linear.

Answer (score 1):

If we define the absolute value function as

$$
  |x| =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if }x \ge 0 \\
-x, & \text{if }x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

then we can use this formulation repeatedly to write out the integrand piecewise and also know where to break up the bounds.

Let $f(x) = ||x+1|-1|$.  Then

$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|x+1|-1,  & \text{if }|x+1| -1 \ge 0 \\
1-|x+1|, & \text{if }|x+1| -1 < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Consider the second of these branches.  $ |x + 1| - 1 < 0 $ can be simplified as $ -2 < x < 0 $.  Therefore, the condition on the first branch splits into two:

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|x+1|-1,  & \text{if }x \ge 0 \\
1-|x+1|, & \text{if }-2 < x < 0 \\
|x+1|-1,  & \text{if }x \le -2 
\end{cases}
$$

Finally, remove the last set of absolute value bars.  $|x+1| = x + 1 $ if $x\ge -1$ and $-(x+1)$ if $x<-1$.  For the outer branches, $x$ is already at least $0$ or less than $-2$, so we can simply swap out $|x+1|$ with the appropriately signed expression.  And since the change occurs at $x=-1$, we can split up the middle branch appropriately as well, yielding

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if }x \ge 0 \\
-x, & \text{if }-1 \le x < 0 \\
x+2, & \text{if }-2 < x < -1 \\
-x-2,  & \text{if }x \le -2 
\end{cases}
$$

From here, the integration should be simple enough.

(The seemingly random use of strict and non-strict inequalities simply comes from the straight application of the initial definition of $|x|$.  They can be cleaned up and made to look more consistent however you like, if that's preferable :).  Of course, they have no impact on the value of your integral.)